# Android app web service hacking

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have a one android application in store.I read and write to my data from web service (JSON).Hackers can download to apk and hack this app and see my web services address ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes its possible Please visit this site upload apk.http://www.javadecompilers.com/result. And if you want to avoid this Apk decompiler you have to use Progard.Visit this for more info https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can if your Web Service is not secured enough. They will not even need to reverse-engineer your app, they could just see to what IP their phone connects when they open the app. So they can get these informations:

- Where your Web Service endpoint is
- What data you are sending to the web service
- What data the service sends back

They could also reverse-enigneer (decompile) your App and see the source code and the logic behind it.

This should not be enough to get into your server. How do they sign on to the Web API? Is there any authentication service?

Comment: I use SSL.https

E.g :

www.domain.com?webservices.php?MethodName=ListStudents&className=12A&username=webserviceuser&password=webservicepassword&returntype=JSON

this web service return to JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I use SSL.https

E.g :

www.domain.com?webservices.php?MethodName=ListStudents&className=12A&username=webserviceuser&password=webservicepassword&returntype=JSON

this web service return to JSON data.

Comment: Please consider to not answer to your own question until you solved it. Instead use the comment function on existing ones. Your clients can read the username and the password. But this should be no problem (I suppose that they know username and password anyway / already entered it). You can optimize the password with hashing it, don't forget to do some security checks on the server (Cross Site Scripting, SQL Injection...). If there are no such problems, you should be safe.

Comment: This username and password is global.It is not user information.